# ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests when triggering from orawsv

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am calling a web service from database procedure using utl_http request, it's working fine if I trigger direct from database,

but if I trigger the procedure using orawsv I am getting the following error

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1339 ORA-29261: bad argument

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130

ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

my DB is :11.2.0.4.0

this video explaining in details my issue with the code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rAqJOpm96TVptp7TEBaHcLi1zSGhc7wY/view?usp=sharing

Please help

Thanks ...

Comment: This is the code:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AjCAV2gjR5OC7UhVRBNM2mZ1MKKowD_T/view?usp=sharing